How to send request from js cordova to PHP? cors system error
When sending a request from a cordova JS request application a CORS error comes out, and I don't understand how to customize the headers.
The application is on different devices, addresses are different everywhere, I can't write one address for the address. I put * instead of address, nothing works.
API is using PHP Slim framework. Code as follows:
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->options('/api/search/', function ($request, $response) {
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
});
$app->post('/api/search', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    $response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    //$response = $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($data));
    return $response;
});

Code for sending a request to PHP:
$.ajax({
  url: "url_adress",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "application/json",
  data: {
    barcode: '123',
    tkn: 'token'
  },
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  },
  success: function (response) {
    let data = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(data);
  },
})

I tried to specify the server address in the server response headers, but nothing worked.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://url....' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I send the request from the browser to the server, the plan is to send requests from cell phones
chrome network requests
The pre-request options are not even displayed

I was able to get everything set up. But now when sending a request from the mobile application there is an ajax 0 error, in the browser everything works correctly

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header. It needs to be sent from PHP.

But CORS shouldn't be an issue if you're not sending the request to a different domain.

You forgot to tell us what the actual error is. There are many different CORS errors

You seem to have some misunderstandings about CORS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for details of how it works. As Barmar says, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is intended as a response header. The server needs to tell the browser which origins it will accept requests from. If the client could set this, CORS would be entirely pointless!

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://url....' from origin 'null'...by any chance are you loading the web page using the file:// URL instead of http://? You really ought to run it properly via a http server or else it won't have an origin

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check...probably your PHP code doesn't handle pre-flight OPTIONS requests...most likely the webserver does that, and doesn't pass them through to PHP. And therefore your Slim middleware has no effect when a pre-flight request occurs, because the request never reaches it. Check your webserver config in the first instance. I note also that the CORS headers you've specified in the PHP code doesn't include OPTIONS as one of the allowed methods either

Is it possible to do without a prior request?

Again, read about CORS. There you will see the conditions which require a pre-flight request to occur. The browser will send one, if those conditions occur. Instead of wasting time trying to see if you can work around the issue, set your server up to deal with them correctly.

But now when sending a request from the mobile application there is an ajax 0 error...this sounds like a new and different problem, which would need a new question. If you solved the CORS issue, post your solution below in the Answers section. Then ask a new question about the error in the mobile app. Thanks.
